# CSS Bottom border should not start from left

Tags: html, css

I have a title. I need border bottom for that.

[image: result]

[image: But I am getting like this]

How to resolve? And need to do

```css
.newTitle {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="newTitle">Stack Overflow</p>
```

Comment: I really didn't understand a thing. Could you explain yourself better please? Thanks! :D

Comment: 1) explain as clearly as possible with no ambiguity.  2) what is the problem? 3) what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: it is still not clear what you want?
which image layout (1st or 2nd in your question) are you trying to achieve

Comment: Getting result currently as down. We want as above

Comment: That's even less explanation than you had in your orignal question! Try to express what you don't want and what you want!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `span` inside your `p` tag and apply the border or class to that span (spans are inline by default, so it's only as long as content/text)

```css
.newTitle {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="newTitle">Stack Overflow</span></p>
```

SECOND SOLUTION after comment of OP to my initial answer:

Put the p-tag into a wrapping DIV and apply padding to that one like in the example below:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.newTitle {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="newTitle">Stack Overflow</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add that this answer was a reply to the initial question, which was phrased quite deifferently (had no pictures, but more words)

Comment: I want border on bottom some long as my first image

Comment: Note my second solution please

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your p tag has some padding. Something like padding-left:50px or so. So what you could do is change the paddinf-left to margin-left. that would do the trick. heres the code

```css
p{
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:50px;
}

.newTitle {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="newTitle">Stack Overflow</p>
```

OR

Instead of using border-bottom, use text-dexoration. that seems more right as it is specifically designed to underline your text.

```css
.newTitle {

  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="newTitle">Stack Overflow</p>
```

Comment: the margin is the answer i believe, but both sides ;) or is it padding (question unclear, which image is the good one ? LOL )

Comment: you're right! the margin is on both the sides. Didnt notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Well your explanation should be better next time but this is what I think is what you want.

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
}
.newTitle {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="newTitle">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:after` to get the desired result without adding html tags.

```css
.newTitle {
  padding:20px;
  background:aqua;
}
.newTitle:after{
  content: " ";
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p class="newTitle">Stack Overflow</p>
```